# Why same matrix have diferent size in parquet

Tags: pandas, matrix, pyspark, parquet, pyarrow

I have a matrix (1470131 x 3000) store in parquet (6.5MB) and I want to get some rows with pyarrow + parquet. I have transpose the matrix (3000 x 1470131) to get the row by column but the size of the file bigger (464MB). Why the transpose storage size si bigger that the original matrix?

Example:

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

matrix = np.matrix([
    np.arange(0, 5),
    np.arange(5, 10),
    np.arange(10, 15),
    np.arange(15, 20),
    np.arange(20, 25),
    np.arange(25, 30),
    np.arange(35, 40),
])


df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(table, 'df.parquet', use_dictionary=True, compression='snappy')


dft = pd.DataFrame(matrix.T)
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(dft)
pq.write_table(table, 'dft.parquet', use_dictionary=True, compression='snappy')

print("Original dataframe size", os.stat('df.parquet').st_size)
print("Transpose dataframe size", os.stat('dft.parquet').st_size)

print("Dataframes are equals", pq.read_table('df.parquet').to_pandas().equals(pq.read_table('dft.parquet').to_pandas().T))
```

```
Original dataframe size 2352
Transpose dataframe size 3080
Dataframes are equals True
```

Comment: Do you have several dtypes in your dataframe ? As the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) quotes, if the dtypes are not homogeneous, all the dataframe is converted to object type. I guess that might impact the size of the whole structure

Comment: My dataframe is a scipy sparse csr_matrix transposed and then transformed to dense format and I create the dataframe from this.

Comment: Parquet is a column-wise storage format. So if the number of columns in your file drastically changes (from 3000 to 1470131), even though the total number of data stays the same, I am not surprised that this has an impact on the compression (which is done column wise).